# How to pass access to a constrained string to a subprogram in Ada

Tags: pointers, ada

Okay. I really hate asking simple questions like this, but I have fully read three different books explain access types and parameter modes to me, and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

I am creating a simple shell in Ada, because I have an interest in this and I think it so far has been a good learning experience. Here is my code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Execute_System;

procedure Main is
   package IO renames Ada.Text_IO;
   Input : aliased String(1 .. 255) := (others=> ' ');
   Last: Integer;

begin
   IO.Put_Line("Welcome to ash! This is an extreme work in progress.");
   Main_Loop:
   loop
      Input := (others=> ' ');
      IO.Put("ash> ");
      IO.Get_Line(Input, Last);
      if Input(Input'First..Last) = "quit" then
       exit Main_Loop;
      else
       Execute_System(Command => Input'Access);
      end if;
   end loop Main_Loop;
end Main;
```

What Execute_System() does is pass to Spawn, which is in turn provided by the GNAT.OS_Lib library. The errors that I get when compiling are:

```
main.adb:6:04: warning: aliased object has explicit bounds
main.adb:6:04: warning: declare without bounds (and with explicit initialization)
main.adb:6:04: warning: for use with unconstrained access
main.adb:19:36: object subtype must statically match designated subtype
execute_system.adb:5:60: prefix of "Access" attribute must be aliased
gnatmake: "main.adb" compilation error
```

I don't understand why I can't give access to this string, just because it has explicit bounds. I've seen a solution in `new subtype Command_Access is access all String(1..255)`, but I don't understand why this is a solution (also pardon the syntax errors, I'm still new to subtyping).

Can someone shed some light on my issue? I have tested the Execute_System procedure with hard-coded values without access parameter mode, so I don't believe it's this issue.

Comment: P.S. You shouldn't include "shell" as a tag, even though you're trying to write a shell.  The reason is that readers' knowledge of shells would not be of any use in answering this question.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the tag.

Comment: The compiler indicates that you also have an error in `execute_system.adb`, so it would be nice if you included that source file as well - or at least fixed the error.

Comment: Is there a reason that you pass an access type to `Execute_System`?

Comment: I would but ajb's answer fixed my issue.  I don't want to post it since now I have another vexing issue. I'm considering making another question.

Comment: What is the signature of Execute_System ?

Comment: @NWS - I had previously tried a (Command : access String) approach, but after these explanations I've changed it to package-wide, making the input line a package wide variable, so now Execute_System's signature is just `procedure Execute_System`.
I don't know particularly where to ask these low-level, high-frequency questions, either. The code compiles, but now conveniently doesn't work, and a `1` is always returned, indicating failure somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a fairly obscure rule (RM 3.10.2(27ff)).  But the reason has to do with implementation difficulties.

When a variable or parameter has type `access String` with no bounds, there must be a way to get the bounds when the variable or parameter is used:

```
procedure Some_Procedure (A : access String) is 
     First, Last : Integer;
begin
     First := A'First;
     Last := A'Last;
     ...
end Some_Procedure;
```

If `A` is essentially just the address of the first character of the string, then there would be no way to compute `A'First` and `A'Last`.

One popular way to solve this is to store the bounds of the string as two integers preceding the first character of the string.  Then, when `S'Access` is used as the value of an `access String;` variable or parameter, the code knows that the first character of the string will be preceded by the bounds, and it can thus retrieve them to get the value of `A'First` and `A'Last`.

The perceived problem with this solution was that it means *every* aliased `String` must have those bounds stored.  (I think it's only necessary for `aliased` objects.)  If you say

```
S : aliased String(1..100);
```

then the compiler has to generate the bounds, because it can't tell whether, at some point in the program (perhaps even in a different package), the code might try to use `S'Access` as the value of an `access String;`.  Those bounds would have to be stored even if `S'Access` were never used like that, since the compiler wouldn't be able to predict what code might do that in the future.  This would lead to wasted space.  Not a good thing, since embedded systems are one of Ada's main targets.

The compromise was to decree that if an aliased `String` `S` did not have the bounds as part of the type, then the bounds would be stored, and you could use `S'Access` for an `access String`.  If the aliased `String` did have bounds as part of the subtype, then the bounds would not be stored, but you couldn't use `S'Access` as an `access String` (you could still use it as an `access String(m..n)` if the bounds matched).  This means that in this case, the bounds are stored:

```
Input : aliased String := (1 .. 255 => ' ');
```

but in this case they're not:

```
Input : aliased String(1 .. 255) := (others=> ' ');
```

The first form is what you could use in your case to get around the problem.

It would be nice if Ada had a way to write a declaration of the second type but still tell the compiler to treat it like the first--i.e. store the bounds and allow the `'Access` to be usable as an `access String`.  In fact, I believe there is an Ada Issue out there (which I don't feel like looking up) proposing a possible syntax for this.  As I recall, there was some discussion of several possible syntaxes and they were all ugly, so the matter was dropped, but it's possible that a future version of Ada might provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

Try change `Input'Access` to `Input'Unrestricted_Access`.

## Attribute Unrestricted_Access

Attribute `Unrestricted_Access` is a feature of GNAT. It can be used for any type.

## Example 1

Commented code lines does not work.

```vhdl
type String_Access is access all String;

function Str_10 return String is
   S : String (1 .. 10);
begin
   return S;
end;

Str_1 : aliased String := "0123456789";
Str_2 : aliased String := Str_10;
Str_3 : aliased String (1 .. 10) := (others => '0');
Str_Acc_1 : String_Access := Str_1'Access;
Str_Acc_2 : String_Access := Str_2'Access;
--Str_Acc_3 : String_Access := Str_3'Access;
--Str_Acc_4 : String_Access := Str_3'Unchecked_Access;
Str_Acc_5 : String_Access := Str_3'Unrestricted_Access;
```

## Example 2

Working [demo](https://ideone.com/KR2RwN) in action.

```vhdl
With Ada.Text_IO; Use Ada.Text_IO;  
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO; Use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Program is
    type String_Access is access all String;
    Str_2 : aliased String (50 .. 60);
    Str_3 : aliased String (1 .. 10) := (others => '0');
    Str_Acc_5 : String_Access := Str_3'Unrestricted_Access;
begin
    Put (Str_Acc_5'First);
    New_Line;
    Put (Str_Acc_5'Last);
    Str_Acc_5 := Str_2'Unrestricted_Access;
    New_Line;
    Put (Str_Acc_5'First);
    New_Line;
    Put (Str_Acc_5'Last);
end Program;
```

## External resources

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gnat_rm/Unrestricted_005fAccess.html

> The Unrestricted_Access attribute is similar to Access except that all accessibility and aliased view checks are omitted. This is a user-beware attribute. It is similar to Address, for which it is a desirable replacement where the value desired is an access type. In other words, its effect is identical to first applying the Address attribute and then doing an unchecked conversion to a desired access type. In GNAT, but not necessarily in other implementations, the use of static chains for inner level subprograms means that Unrestricted_Access applied to a subprogram yields a value that can be called as long as the subprogram is in scope (normal Ada 95 accessibility rules restrict this usage).
>
> It is possible to use Unrestricted_Access for any type, but care must be exercised if it is used to create pointers to unconstrained objects. In this case, the resulting pointer has the same scope as the context of the attribute, and may not be returned to some enclosing scope. For instance, a function cannot use Unrestricted_Access to create a unconstrained pointer and then return that value to the caller.

## Comments

@ajb stated in the comments that bouandery `Str_Acc_5'First = Str_3'First` and `Str_Acc_5'Last = Str_3'Last` may or may not be true. Currently I cannot find official documentation on that yet. On the other hand the [boundary is matching on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/KR2RwN).

Comment: Have you double-checked to make sure that `Str_Acc_5'First` and `Str_Acc_5'Last` are 1 and 10 as expected?  See my answer for an explanation of why this might not work.  `'Unrestricted_Access` is defined by GNAT, not by Ada, and it lets you get around some of the rules, which can be useful when interfacing with C or other languages (which wouldn't know about where to find the array bounds anyway).  But I'm not 100% convinced that this approach will work when `Str_Acc_5` is used by other Ada code.  **It must be tested.**